# Error when Reading from stdin in C Program: @rror opening file

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a C program that reads input and calculates word counts. The program works well in most cases, but I'm encountering an error when reading from stdin using the `echo | ./wordcount` command. The error message I'm receiving is:  @rror opening file: ▒▒1▒I▒▒^H▒▒H▒▒▒PTI▒▒@

Code Snippets:

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Define constants for the flags
#define FLAG_LINES 1
#define FLAG_WORDS 2
#define FLAG_BYTES 4

// Define the default flags to be all of the counts
#define DEFAULT_FLAGS (FLAG_LINES | FLAG_WORDS | FLAG_BYTES)

// Define a structure to hold the counts and file name
typedef struct {
  int lines;
  int words;
  int bytes;
  char *file_name;
} WcData;

// Parse the command line arguments
int parse_args(int argc, char **argv, int *flags, char **file_name) {
  // Set the flags to the default
  *flags = 0;

  // Parse the command line arguments
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    // Check if the current argument is a flag
    if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
      // Parse the flags
      for (int j = 1; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) {
        if (argv[i][j] == 'l') {
          *flags |= FLAG_LINES;
        } else if (argv[i][j] == 'w') {
          *flags |= FLAG_WORDS;
        } else if (argv[i][j] == 'c') {
          *flags |= FLAG_BYTES;
        } else {
          // If an invalid flag is encountered, print an error message and return
          fprintf(stderr, "Invalid flag: %c\n", argv[i][j]);
          return 0;
        }
      }
    } else {
      // If a non-flag argument is encountered, it should be the file name
      *file_name = argv[i];
    }
  }

  // Return success
  return 1;
}

// Compute the counts for the given file
int compute_counts(FILE *file, int flags, WcData *data) {
  // Initialize the counts to 0
  data->lines = 0;
  data->words = 0;
  data->bytes = 0;

  // Read the file one character at a time
  int c, last_c = '\0';
  while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    // Increment the byte count
    data->bytes++;

    // Check if the character is a newline
    if (c == '\n') {
      data->lines++;
    }

    // Check if the character is a word separator
    if (isspace(c) || ispunct(c)) {
      // Check if the previous character was not a word separator
      if (!isspace(last_c) && !ispunct(last_c)) {
        // Increment the word count
        data->words++;
      }
    }

// Save the current character for the next iteration
last_c = c;
  }

  // Check if the last character was not a word separator
  if (!isspace(last_c) && !ispunct(last_c)) {
    // Increment the word count
    data->words++;
  }

  // Return success
  return 1;
}

// Print the counts for the given data
void print_counts(int flags, WcData data) {
  // Print the line count if the flag is set
  if (flags & FLAG_LINES) {
    printf("%d ", data.lines);
  }

  // Print the word count if the flag is set
  if (flags & FLAG_WORDS) {
    printf("%d ", data.words);
  }

  // Print the byte count if the flag is set
  if (flags & FLAG_BYTES) {
    printf("%d ", data.bytes);
  }

  // Print the file name
  printf("%s\n", data.file_name);
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Parse the command line arguments
  int flags;
  char *file_name;
  if (!parse_args(argc, argv, &flags, &file_name)) {
    // If the arguments are invalid, return an error code
    return 1;
  }

  // Open the file
  FILE *file;
  if (file_name == NULL) {
    // If no file name was given, read from stdin
    file = stdin;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, open the specified file
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
      // If the file could not be opened, print an error message and return an error code
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", file_name);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // Compute the counts
  WcData data;
    data.file_name = file_name;

  if (!compute_counts(file, flags, &data)) {
    // If the counts could not be computed, return an error code
    return 1;
  }

  // Print the counts
  print_counts(flags, data);

  // Close the file
  if (file != stdin) {
    fclose(file);
  }

  // Return success
  return 0;
}
```

Problem Description:

I'm seeking assistance with resolving this error and making sure that when I use the echo | ./wordcount command, the program prompts me to input the file name and any specific flags from the command line.

This is my test file

```
Test_wordcount.sh
#! /bin/bash
#echo "words, words, words" | ./wordcount

echo | ./wordcount -l file_name.txt
echo | ./wordcount -w file_name.txt
echo | ./wordcount -c -l  file_name.txt

echo | ./wordcount -l new.txt
echo | ./wordcount -w new.txt
echo | ./wordcount -c new.txt

echo | ./wordcount file_name.txt
./wordcount
```

Testing results

```
vm-hw07{asharm13}148: ./test_wordcount.sh
6 file_name.txt
15 file_name.txt
6 83 file_name.txt
11 new.txt
53 new.txt
5226 new.txt
6 15 83 file_name.txt
@rror opening file: ▒▒1▒I▒▒^H▒▒H▒▒▒PTI▒▒@
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to how the program handles stdin and file inputs in this particular scenario. Despite trying different approaches, I have not been able to resolve the error.

Any assistance in identifying the cause of the error and guiding me towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `parse_args` doesn't handle the case where there is no filename argument. Since you never initialized `file_name`, you're using an uninitialized pointer when calling `fopen()`.

Comment: Initialize your variable: `char *file_name = NULL;`

Comment: You should use `getopt()` or friends to parse your arguments. You've rolled your own version and not made a good job of it.

Comment: Aside: some text files do not end with a `\n`. (Saves one byte.) If the file contained only `foo bar`, your program would claim there are 7 characters making up 2 words on 0 lines... Something's not right...

Comment: Aside #2: How do you deal with digits? `"88 piano keys"` counts 3 words. `"pi is 3.14"` counts 4 words... Slightly irregular...

Comment: You are correct but can you help me sort out this issue first? segmentation fault

Comment: `data.file_name = file_name;` Well, the first test cast in that shell script does not supply a filename... The code doesn't use the DEFAULT_FLAGS, so the only output comes from `printf("%s\n", data.file_name);`... This is UB... Learn to read the code you write and think about each variable as you use them... ALWAYS initialise variables to have a definite value! `WcData data;` MORE uninitialised counters here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *file_name;` is not initialized. If you do not pass the file name, the function `parse_args` does not assign anything.

Then you use this pointer, which invokes undefined behaviour.

The cure:

```
char *file_name = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the after doing this now I am getting thi error of segmentation fault...vm-hw07{asharm13}357: ./test_wordcount.sh
6 file_name.txt
15 file_name.txt
6 83 file_name.txt
11 new.txt
53 new.txt
5226 new.txt
6 15 83 file_name.txt
 -w new.txt
./test_wordcount.sh: line 15: 3122713 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./wordcount
after checking with valgrind -g debugger I am getting Invalid read of size 1
==3122754==    at 0x4C3E056: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:494)
==31227  by 0x400BE4: print_counts (problem3.c:196)